# How can I rename multiple files within a single directory, to remove the timestamp at the end of the file name?

Tags: bash, shell-script, rename

How can I rename the files below on Linux to remove the time stamp from the file name?

```
AB_CD_EFGHIKL_20191221_D_1.dat.20191221102446_processed
AB_CD_EFGHIKLMN_20191221_D_1.dat.20191221102428_processed
```

I want to rename the files to:

```
AB_CD_EFGHIKL_20191221_D_1.dat
AB_CD_EFGHIKLMN_20191221_D_1.dat
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have `perl-rename` (called `rename` on Debian and Ubuntu and many others), you can do:

```bsh
rename -n 's/dat\.\d+_processed/dat/' *.dat*
```

The `-n` makes it just print out the changes it would make without actually renaming anything. If that works, run the command again but without the `-n`.

---

Alternatively, you can do it in the shell:

```
for f in *.dat*; do echo mv -- "$f" "${f%.dat*}.dat"; done
```

Once again, if that does what you need, remove the `echo` and run it again.

Comment: Thanks looks good but, it's removing the .dat also but it should be there end of the each and every file.
AB_CD_EFGHIKLMN_20191221_D_1

Comment: @kotideveloper He had a slight typo in the parameter substitution in the second piece of code. It is fixed now.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you.looks good now.